# MySQL Error 1005?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a database, but am getting a strange error... This is my code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Person`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Address`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Email`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Airport`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customer`;

CREATE TABLE Address
(
AddressID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(AddressID),
AddressStreet VARCHAR(255),
AddressCity VARCHAR(255),
AddressState VARCHAR(255),
AddressZip VARCHAR(255),
AddressCountry VARCHAR(255)
);


CREATE TABLE Email
(
EmailID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(EmailID),
EmailAddress VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Person
(
PersonID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(PersonID),
PersonCode VARCHAR(255),
PersonLastName VARCHAR(255),
PersonFirstName VARCHAR(255),
AddressID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY `fk_Person_to_Address` (AddressID) REFERENCES Address(AddressID),
PersonPhone VARCHAR(255),
EmailID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY `fk_Person_to_Email` (EmailID) REFERENCES Email(EmailID)
);

CREATE TABLE Airport
(
AirportID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(AirportID),
AirportCode VARCHAR(255),
AirportName VARCHAR(255),
AddressID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY `fk_Airport_to_Address` (AddressID) REFERENCES Address(AddressID),
AirportLatDeg INT NOT NULL,
AirportLatMin INT NOT NULL,
AirportLongDeg INT NOT NULL,
AirportLongMin INT NOT NULL,
AirportPassFacilityFee FLOAT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
CustomerID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID),
CustomerCode VARCHAR(255),
CustomerType VARCHAR(255),
PrimaryContact VARCHAR(255),
FOREIGN KEY `fk_Customer_to_Person` (PrimaryContact) REFERENCES Person(PersonID),
CustomerName VARCHAR(255),
CustomerAirlineMiles FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

Everything goes great until I get to the Customer table and I try to rename one of the foreign keys. This is the error I'm getting...

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'myName.Customer' (errno: 150)
```

I've tried to look at some other examples of this error but am not understanding the problem. Is it because I'm trying to rename a foreign key in the Customer table? What I want is to get the PersonID from the Person table, but rename it primaryContact in the Customer table. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a foreign key, the data types should match that of the primary key.  Change the `PrimaryContact` field in the `Customer` table to match the data type of `PersonId`, in this case, `int`:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
CustomerID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID),
CustomerCode VARCHAR(255),
CustomerType VARCHAR(255),
PrimaryContact int,
FOREIGN KEY `fk_Customer_to_Person` (PrimaryContact) REFERENCES Person(PersonID),
CustomerName VARCHAR(255),
CustomerAirlineMiles FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

The columns must be of the same type as seen in the manual page entitled [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was such a simple little error that could be giving me such a headache.